# How to change variable value without doing it manually

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For example I have this code in **library.jsx**:

```
const numberOfPages = 1;

const getNumberOfPages = () => numberOfPages;
```

I do not want to change the **library.jsx** file manually but would like to set the numberOfPages value somehow by using a bash script or anything similar that will automate this proccess.

Comment: This very much sounds like an http://xyproblem.info. Please provide more context.

Comment: Not really. I understand that what I am asking might be strange but is exactly what I need to achieve. To be able to edit a file with a script and not by hand.

Comment: What have you tried then? A bash script to change a line in a file should be fairly simple.

Comment: Yes but I would like to see if there are more elegant ways of doing something like this, so I wanted to ask and see if someone has a different idea.

Comment: Well, since changing a line in a file is what you’re asking for, that’s a somewhat straight forward task in virtually any language. For different ideas, which would preferably avoid doing this at all, we’d need to have more information about what you’re trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a script that modifies the `library.jsx` file programmatically -

```
  const fs = require('fs');

// Define the new value for numberOfPages
const newNumberOfPages = 2;

// Read the content of library.jsx
fs.readFile('library.jsx', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }

  // Replace the value of numberOfPages with the new value
  const updatedContent = data.replace(/const numberOfPages = \d+;/, `const numberOfPages = ${newNumberOfPages};`);

  // Write the updated content back to library.jsx
  fs.writeFile('library.jsx', updatedContent, 'utf8', (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }
    console.log('numberOfPages value updated successfully!');
  });
});
```

save this file as `updateNumberOfPages.js` and run it with Node.js.

and run it with - `node updateNumberOfPages.js`

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the time, I have thought of such way and it definetly will work and if nothing else appears as an answer I will accept this one. But want to check if someone will come up with a more "elegant" way of doing it.

Comment: I'm glad that you liked it